# RegisterClientScriptBlock not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

my RegisterClientScriptBlock is not exicuting for some reason

my code on vb.net

```
Private Sub Update_Chart(ByRef Table As DataSet) 

 (more code but not needed, such as arrays)


  Dim script As String
    script = _
    "function chart()" & _
    "{" & _
   "var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();" & _
    "chart.redraw();" & _
    " }" & _
        ";"


    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock( _
        Me, _
        GetType(Page), _
        "container1", _
        script, _
        True)
```

any ideas on why?

Comment: What method is this in?

Comment: its in,  Private Sub Update_Chart(ByRef Table As DataSet)

Comment: It shouldn't execute immediately, what it does is putting this line into your markup: <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function chart(){chart.redraw(); };//]]>
</script>

Comment: how come, and how do i execute it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is simply defining a javascript function. Functions are not executed until they are called. Try this instead:

```
Dim script As String
script = "chart.redraw();"

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock( _
    Me, _
    GetType(Page), _
    "container1", _
    script, _
    True)
```

Comment: i have, but it trows an error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: chart is not defined

Comment: @mali - you have to put it after you define your chart object, where do you define it ?

Comment: In that case, your issue is with referencing your javascript chart object. You may need to add it to the global scope in javascript or use jQuery to select the element. I can't help further without more code.

Comment: well before i did have this :        "   var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();" & _

Comment: It looks like if you combine those two lines, it should work. Are you getting another error?

Comment: yeah lol: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'redraw' of undefined

Comment: So I think what's happening is that the page is doing a full postback, which reloads the page and completely destroys the chart. In that case, your chart needs to be recreated on page load, and the redraw may not even be needed. In either case, the two lines of code in your RegisterClientScriptBlock are probably running before the page is loaded.